# Simulating stock rates

Tags: java, random

I want to make a program that simulates stock rates, in which the data is random. I am using the random() method in Math to generate the numbers. The program adds a float and after some limit it subtracts it. My problem is: I want some sudden fall and rise in values. How can I generate this?

Here is my code:

```
private static float lastValue= 50.187786f;
private static float limit=49.627786f;
private static float min_value=0.334834f;

private float randomValue() {

double factor = Math.random()/10;


if (lastValue >limit+min_value){
    lastValue=lastValue-(float)factor;
}else if(limit<limit-min_value){
    lastValue = lastValue + (float) factor;
}else{
    lastValue = lastValue + (float) factor;  
}
```

Comment: have two random numbers. The first determines the magnitude multiplier of the second. The first could be pro-rated in some fashion to make the spikes less (or more) common (so if it's .8 or less, the multiplier is 1. If it's more than .8, the multiplier is 5, for example)

Comment: I feel like there is some kind of meta-comment to be made about a sign of the times and modelling stock market behaviour with random number generators.

Comment: i tried that but it is showing either increase or decrease continually but not sudden drops and peaks. Ho to implement a algorithm for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock markets are usually modelled as a random walk. i.e. you have an equal chance of going up or down one value.  i.e.

```
price += Math.random() >= 0.5 ? +1 : -1;
```

You can add to your model that there are quieter times (less moves per second) and busier times (more moves per second).

Modelling news events (which cause sudden increase, decreases or holds of a stock) is more complex. I would model this separately. i.e. you have a very small chance that the price will move much more than normal.